# Calling another observable during onComplete

Tags: android, rx-java, rx-java2

I have an api call which is a `Completable`. If Api call is success I have to clear some temp db values (don't do this if api call fails) For clearing temp values from db I have another `Completable` method. What I have done initially was something like this.

```
           apiCall()
                    .observeOn(Schedulers.io())
                    .doOnComplete(() -> clearTempDb())
                    .subscribeWith(new DisposableCompletableObserver() {
                        @Override
                        public void onComplete() {
                            Log.d(TAG, "onComplete: ");
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onError(Throwable e) {
                            Log.e(TAG, "onError: " + e.getMessage());
                        }
                    });


        private Completable clearTempDb() {
            return Completable.fromAction(() -> {
                Log.d(TAG, "clear temp db started");
                Thread.sleep(2000);
                Log.d(TAG, "clear temp db completed");
            }).subscribeOn(Schedulers.io());
        }

        private Completable apiCall() {
            return Completable.fromAction(() -> Thread.sleep(2000)).subscribeOn(Schedulers.io());
        }
```

Then I realized that in `doOnComplete` calling just `clearTempDb()` wont work unless you subscribe to it. 
So I changed it to

```
                     apiCall()
                    .observeOn(Schedulers.io())
                    .doOnComplete(() -> clearTempDb().subscribe())
                    .subscribeWith(new DisposableCompletableObserver() {
                        @Override
                        public void onComplete() {
                            Log.d(TAG, "onComplete: ");
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onError(Throwable e) {
                            Log.e(TAG, "onError: " + e.getMessage());
                        }
                    });
```

That works , but what happens is any error occurred in the `clearTempDb` would not be a part of the main stream and will not be passed to the actual subscribers `onError` 
Then I made `clearTempDb` as a part of the main observable chain, like

```
apiCall().andThen(clearTempDb())
```

Now it is working as expected. But the issue is `apiCall` and `clearTempDb` have become sequential. which means after completing these 2 only `onComplete` will be called. But I don't want to wait till the `clearTempDb` to finish, to complete my main observable. 
Again I went back to the `doOnComplete` with error ignored

```
             apiCall()               
            .doOnComplete(()->clearTempDb().onErrorComplete().subscribe())
            .subscribeWith(new DisposableCompletableObserver() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete() {
                    Log.d(TAG, "onComplete: ");
                }

                @Override
                public void onError(Throwable e) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "onError: " + e.getMessage());
                }
            });
```

Now its working fine but I don't know whether it is the proper solution or not. Because in many tutorials I have seen that doing any heavy task in the `doOnNext`, `doOnComplete` or such intermediate events are not recommended as it will be outside of your observable chain and its kind of interrupting an active observable chain. So how can I do it in the proper way?  Is `apiCall().andThen(clearTempDb())` the recommended and only possible way?

Comment: There is a conceptional problem with your requirement: you don't want to wait for the clearTempDB completing normally but you'd like to have its error, if that happens, within the same parent stream. Since both onError and onComplete are terminal events, you can either wait for a terminal event or don't wait for it.

Comment: So, in case if I don't want to wait and the error can be ignored as well,  `doOnComplete(()->clearTempDb().onErrorComplete().subscribe())` is the recommended way?

Comment: Yes, that's a possible approach.